# Stop fullscreen HTML5 video rotating on trigger

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-video, screen-orientation

If I trigger fullscreen in Chrome Android, portrait mode it automatically rotates the fullscreen video to landscape.

To get it back to portrait fullscreen I have to rotate the device landscape then back to portrait.

How can I launch fullscreen to match the orientation that the user is using?

*i.e if the device is in portrait and I trigger fullscreen it opens in portrait fullscreen, and if the device is in landscape it triggers landscape fullscreen*

I still want to be able to rotate my device to change orientation, I just want it to match the native orientation. It works fine in the emulator on Mac Chrome, just not on my Android mobile device.

```
videoSmallTrigger.on('click', function() {

     if (!document.isFullScreen && !document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
       openFullscreen(videoSmallID);
        body.addClass('fullscreen-video-sm');
        videoSmall.get(0).play();

    }
});

function openFullscreen(element) {
   
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Comment: Couldn't find a proper solution, so in the end I think I just made my own fullscreen video that I triggered like a modal like this:


```position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;```

Think I added a black overlay, or just hid the page content beneath to give it a full screen effect.

Hope that's helpful!